# how to install "linux subsystem" in my windows?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-10-v1607

i tried everything powershell, enabling developer mode everything
and nothing seems to work.
Tried with:

```
DISM.exe /Online /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /NoRestart
```

The result i get using powershell:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> DISM.exe /Online /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /NoRest

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.14393.0

Image Version: 10.0.14393.0    


    Error: 0x800f080c

Feature name Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux is unknown.
A Windows feature name was not recognized.
Use the /Get-Features option to find the name of the feature in the image and tr
y the command again.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

some one could explain me how to enable or why i cant use linux subsystem in my windows???

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Comment: You've left out all the useful information. What version of Windows are you using? What error messages do you get? What did the event log say? If you're comfortable getting into 'developer modo' and using `DISM.exe`, you should be able to provide some of these extra details.

Comment: After you have installed WSL you need to go to the Windows Store and install the distribution you want

Comment: i included the error using powershell but i dont have the option to enable linux subsystem.

Comment: @Mokubai - Windows Store is only used to install WSL distributions if you are using Windows 10 1709.  The author is using Windows 10 Version 1607.

Comment: @SergioRamos - I cannot understand a single word in those error messages If you want my help.  Convert it to English.

Comment: @Ramhound I thought it reasonable to assume that they would be on the latest version rather than one that is a year and a half out of date. The information was not in the question when I mentioned it.

Comment: @Mokubai - I don't know what to say.  I agree the author should be using 1709.

Comment: @SergioRamos - Provide an English version of the DISM log file.  You have enabled Developer Mode I presume?  Why are you trying to enable this feature with `/Enable-Feature` instead of `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature` anyways?

Comment: @SergioRamos  I don't know if this is possible but can you perhaps change your language version so that you can still give the exact error message, but in english?

Comment: @SergioRamos I found the exact error and put it into english via https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/42177bef-4d89-4d70-8ae6-0e93e41308b5/restore-corruption-image-in-windows-10-using-deployment-image-servicing-and-management-tool-version?forum=win10itprosetup and https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/7979395e-8870-4e60-a7d2-128c0f51ad84/error-0x800f080c-feature-name-printinglpdprintservice-is-unknown?forum=winservercore that may help some people address your question

Answer (score 1):

> I tried everything PowerShell, enabling developer mode everything and
>   nothing seems to work.

You are using the incorrect command.

You should be using `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux` instead.  You must run this command in an elevated PowerShell command prompt.  You should restart when prompted.

Once you have installed the feature, run through the rest of the instructions, to actually install `Ubuntu on Windows` the above procedure only installs WSL.

[image]

You can verify the name of the feature by using this command.

```
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-*
```

Comment: I would like to note.  The command in question might only be valid for Windows 10 Version 1709.  Until 1709 WSL was listed as a Beta feature from within the `Turn Windows features on and off` tool.  I cannot determine what the actual module name is called on Versions 1511+ at this time.  If you want the procedure to work as-is, upgrade to Version 1709, and call it a day.

Comment: I provided a command to verify the name of the feature, use the correct name if it isn't `Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux`